# Difference between birthday formulas in SQL server programming

Tags: sql-server, formula, date

I am an intern at a company that is teaching me how to program queries for the first time in SQL server and I had a question about a formula I ran across while doing one of their tickets. It's a stored procedure that runs every week to send out happy birthday emails to anyone with a birthday in the coming week. It seems simple enough, but there was something that kind of bothered me about the complexity of the formula they used that someone at my internship actually got from here.
    `Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, dateOfBirth, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1) / 365.25 as int)
    - Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, dateOfBirth, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+7) / 365.25 as int) 
    <> 0`
I understand what that it is taking the current age of the employee and seeing if they are the same age in a week and if not they have a birthday, but I thought that it was kind of messy looking so I wanted to see what I could make from scratch. What I came up with was this.
    `DATEPART(DY, dateOfBirth) - DATEPART(DY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 0
AND DATEPART(DY, dateOfBirth) - DATEPART(DY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < 8`
To me this looked cleaner and simpler, but when I ran the query it came back with more employees than the previous code. My question is why would it come back with a different outcome and is this a viable way to find the birthdays?

Comment: Immediately it looks like the original query accounts for 6 days, and yours accounts for 7. The original query starts tomorrow `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+1` ... `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+7` and yours would include today. I may be misreading that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the original code is not taking today into account, it always starts tomorrow, which may be one reason why your new code is finding more people.

However, consider your logic:

`DATEPART(DY,dateOfBirth) - DATEPART(DY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 0`

According to this, if my date of birth was January 1st (`datepart(dy, dateOfBirth) = 1`) and you ran this on December 31st (`datepart(dy, current_timestamp) = 365`) you would fail the above constraint.

Using the original code gives you static integers regardless of the day of the year.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am new to this whole thing but when I ran the queries I ordered them by DOB and the first row and last row of both queries looked the same and appeared to be the same dates, so I'm not sure if my version was checking an extra day, however, i did not think to check for changing years for some reason. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @JonnyWesley no worries. What I meant by the original code starting tomorrow is that your code is checking against today. So if someone had a birthday today and you ran it today, you would also fail that first constraint, because it would equal zero. By starting tomorrow, you're looking at the next 7 days, and even if someone had a bday tomorrow, you wouldn't equal zero with the original code.